# Homeomorphism of regular surface

Tags: differential-geometry

In Do Carmo's Differential Geometry of Curves and Sufaces chapter 2-2 proposition 4, he mentioned that:

If $p\in S$ is a point of a regular surface $S$ and $\textbf{x}:U\subset\mathbb R^2\to \mathbb R^3$ be a differentiable injection with $p\in\textbf x(U)$ such that $d\textbf{x}$ is injective, then $\textbf{x}$ is a homeomorphism.

The proof is attached [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T7c80.jpg). Here the proof only use the fact that $\textbf x$ is differentiable bijecive and the tangent plane exists, without using regularity of $S$. So I checked the proof carefully and I found that in order to make the proof correct, $\textbf x(V_1)$ in the proof must be open. How to use regularity to show this result?

Comment: Meaning homeomorphism  onto $\mathbf{x}(U)$.

Comment: @Rene Schipperus: The regularity implies there exists a function $\textbf y:U'\to \mathbb R^3$ such that $\textbf y$ is a homeomorphism with its image. But $\textbf y$ is not necessarily equal to $\textbf x$

Comment: Is the problem resolved? I came across the same question.